# What do the Asian women in bathing suit holding fishes pictures on Molly's computer mean?

Tags: fargo-tv

In *Fargo* series, episode *Eating the Blame* (S01E04), when getting back on her computer, Molly briefly sees Asian women in bathing suit holding fishes pictures on her computer appearing for a few seconds, then disappearing.

[image: picture1]

[image: picture2]

I don't remember it being mentioned again... is there a meaning on this, or is it just another Fargo nonsense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personally think it is symbolic that after the previous chief of the police died in line of duty, how the new chief has run this police department into a joke.

- The new police chief has lots of interests in fish, one of the first things he does is to hang a huge fish trophy on his wall.
- It is also kind of sarcastic to show an Asian lady (in those pictures, shown as a trophy girl), holding a fish (a trophy too), in one picture.

Or there is a slim chance the police chief has been using Molly's PC to look for those pictures and forgetting to close them off.